# Using non-STA threads in VSTO projects to achieve parallelism?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, vsto, sta

It's clear that using a [VSTO application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/threading-support-in-office?view=vs-2017), the main Office application is running an STA thread, and spawning other STA threads pose no problem (actually they do provide some challenges but we can handle them). The reason is that STA threads ensure that one thread accesses a COM object at any given time if I understood correctly. And STA is like saying that just one thread can run at any given time.

But in theory, can we spawn a thread which is neither STA (and maybe neither MTA), to achieve true parallelism, assuming we do no COM related operation? Or does STA only apply to COM objects in the sense that parallelism is possible, but STA just does not allow this as far as COM is concerned?

Answer (score 0):

You are free to use non-STA threads (for your own purposes) if you **do not access Office objects** from those threads, and if you **do not access UI** from those threads. You just need to guarantee that those threads are terminated when the add-in is unloaded. In this case, the office application won't even know that your threads exist.

Comment: If I have a thread which does some work accessing Office objects and some work which is totally unrelated to accessing Office objects, I rightly set it to STA. However, will all code end up marshaled to run on the main thread, OR only the Office object calls will be?

Comment: Could you clarify on why you need to guarantee that those threads are terminated when the add-in is unloaded? Is this something which STA takes care of by default and other settings do not?

Comment: You need to quit all threads (i.e. thread functions need to quit), otherwise the office app will possibly crash on exit. Means, you need to notify all your threads to quit when the app is being unloaded and wait until those threads do quit (and the thread should quit upon receiving such a notification, obviously). The "Addin_Unload" may be a good place to notify and wait. It is your choice how to implement that exactly. Check out "CancellationToken" for example. About the marshaling - this is a COM term, so unless you use COM (i.e. access COM objects) nothing will be marshaled.